# Unknown 'DataDriver' library while using excel file

Tags: excel, selenium, robotframework

Implementing a datadriven framework using .xlsx file as external data source for a robot datadriven framework.
I have added the code as -
Library    DataDriver  ../TestData/Login.xlsx  sheet_name=Sheet1
but throwing error as - "Unknown 'DataDriver' library. Try to use Quick Fix (Ctrl+1) or add library to red.xml for proper validation"

I have added the library to red.xml file as given - ‪C:/Python/Lib/site-packages/DataDriver/**init**.py and I have used pip install --upgrade robotframework-datadriver to install. Am i missing anything else? Python version is 3.10.1

Answer (score 0):

It worked by rebuilding the project. (Project > Build Automatically)